# Using OTF to add math equations in Illustrator

Tags: fonts, illustrator

Illustrator has been warning me about ending support for Type 1 fonts, but I didn't listen because I had no idea that my Latex fonts were Type 1. Today I opened my document and the font is no longer recognized (I had previously installed the fonts using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/433232/59344) and everything worked great). Now, I found this [other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656089/59344)  that explains exactly what happened and suggests that fonts will still display but with limited editing capabilities. That was however not my case, as all I see now is this:

[image]

I then tried to use XeLaTeX instead and installed the suggested .otf fonts in my windows folder, adding the following lines to my preamble, and compiled in TeXworks using XeLaTeX:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} 
\usepackage{xunicode} 
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{cmb10.otf} %one of the fonts I installed
```

But that partially worked, as now I see this instead:

[image]

cmb10.otf is installed on Windows, so Illustrator should be able to find it.

How can I fix this? What exactly is the problem? Maybe I am using the wrong font, but what font should I use instead? Or maybe my problem is due to some other reason? ALL my figures will be corrupted because of this. Is there another solution? I am not a big fan of [this alternative](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/433308/59344).

Comment: PD: Thanks to user @LdBeth who helped me in a comment at the other question, but this question got too long to continue in comments.

Comment: `\setmainfont` only affects the text font; probably the fonts in the mathematics were still type 1. Try something like `\usepackage{unicode-math}\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}`. (I'm not sure the Bakoma fonts like cmb10.otf are unicode compliant but I haven't tried them.)

Comment: as @frabjous says use unicode-math , also do not use xunicode or xltxtra in xelatex unless you really need them for compatibility.